# How would I insert a number into a pre-existing script in and repeat 3544 times

Tags: python

I have a script for a video game modification that has to be repeated 3544 times.

```
country_event = {

    id = 5893X
    title = "Aquire $PROVINCENAME$"
    desc = "$COUNTRY$ is surrendering a province to us."
    picture = "administration"

     trigger = {
        has_country_flag = won_acquire_prov
        NOT = { has_country_flag = prov_treaty } 
        any_country = {
            limit = {
                truce_with = THIS
                NOT = {
                    X = {
                        owned_by = THIS
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    option = {
        name = "Take $PROVINCENAME$"
        X = {
            secede_province = THIS
        }
    }
    option = {
        name = "We don't want $PROVINCENAME$"
    }
    option = {
        name = "End Province arbitration"
        set_country_flag = prov_treaty
    }
}
```

The goal is to replace "X"  with a number ranging from 1 to 3544 for each number there will be another "country_event". But I am not sure how to do this.

I have tried using a python script:

```py
infile = open("provids.txt", "r")
outfile = open("0_provs_event.txt","w")
for line in infile:
    if len(line) > 5:
        if line[5] == "=":
            prov = line.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]
            if prov != "REB":
            #^^^ Code does not change file if above is removed
                newline = "country_event = { id = 5893" + prov + "title = Aquire $PROVINCENAME$ desc = $COUNTRY$ is surrendering a province to us. picture = administration trigger = { has_country_flag = won_aquire_prov NOT = { has_country_flag = prov_treaty } any_country = { limit = { truce_with = THIS NOT = {" + tag + "= { owned_by = THIS } } } } } option = { name = Take $PROVINCENAME$ " + prov + " = { secede_province = THIS } } option = { name = We don't want $PROVINCENAME$ } option = { name = End Province arbitration set_country_flag = prov_treaty } } \n"
                outfile.write(newline)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I haven't been able to get it to work. It just makes the file and does nothing else.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how your code relates to the file you have provided? E.g., I don't see any place in it where `line[5] == "="` would be true. There is also no place with a `/`, so how could `prov = line.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]` work? Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score -1):

The main issue is how you're reading in `infile`

When you call `open`, python will open the file as `'_io.TextIOWrapper'` which is a class that contains metadata about the file among other things. If you want the text of the file as a list of strings, where each string is a line of the file (which appears to be what you want), you then need to `read` the file. This can be done using `infile.read()` if you want the whole this as a single string, or `infile.readlines()` if you want each line to be an element of a list

My preferred way of reading in files in python is as follows:

```py
# Setup file paths, and something to store your output which will be written to outfile_path
infile_path = "path_to_infile"
outfile_path = "path_to_outfile"
outfile = []

with open(infile_path, 'r') as f: # Open infile_path into f as a readable object
    infile = f.readlines() # Read through f and place each line as an element in a list
    for line in infile:
        # do stuff, append lines to outfile

outfile = "\n".join(outfile) # Turn the list outfile into a string with character returns between each line
with open(outfile_path, 'w') as f: # Open outfile_path into f as a writable object
    f.write(outfile) # Write out the string outfile to f
```

The advantage of the `with open` version is you don't need to remember to close the file afterwards, that automatically happens after the `with` block (after the unindent in the code)

Comment: `for line in infile` is a common and idiomatic way to iterate over the lines of a file. There's no need to call `read()` or `readlines()`.

Comment: So what would be the best way to approach this. It would be nice to have a guide for reading text files for input for processing but I will try this to see if it works.